# Why does my <ul> become hidden in desktop mode?

Tags: html-lists, navbar, display, hidden

Sorry if this question has already been asked, I don't find anything similar.
So I am following a course and I have created the mobile navbar, which works. Then I write the mediaquery for larger screens and the list, instead of being displayed to the right of the navbar, is hidden.

If I inspect the page I can see that the list and the list items are on the right spot, but they are not visible. I have tried with "visibility: visible" but it doesnt' work.

Where is the mistake?

```js
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
collapsibles.forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("collapsible--expanded");
  })
);
```

```css
/* Typography */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #2584ff;
  --color-secondary: #00d9ff;
  --color-accent: #ff3400;
  --color-headings: #1b0760;
  --color-body: #918ca4;
  --color-border: #ccc;
  --border-radius: 30px;
  --color-body-darker: #5c5577;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--color-body);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: var(--color-headings);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 7rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 8rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
}

/* Links */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link-arrow {
  color: var(--color-accent);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.link-arrow::after {
  content: "-->";
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: margin 0.15s;
}

.link-arrow:hover::after {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .link-arrow {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

/* Badges   */

.badge {
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.badge--primary {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: white;
}

.badge--secondary {
  background: var(--color-secondary);
  color: white;
}

.badge--small {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .badge {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .badge--small {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

/* Lists */

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: var(--color-headings);
}

.list--inline .list__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.list--tick {
  list-style-image: url(/images/tick.svg);
  padding-left: 3rem;
}

.list--tick .list__item {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .list--tick .list__item {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

/* Icons */

.icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.icon--small {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.icon--primary {
  fill: var(--color-primary);
}

.icon--white {
  fill: white;
}

.icon-container {
  background: #f3f9fa;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-container--accent {
  background: var(--color-accent);
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn--primary {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  color: white;
}

.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #8a91f3;
}

.btn--secondary {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  color: white;
}

.btn--accent {
  background-color: var(--color-accent);
  color: white;
}

.btn--accent:hover {
  background: #e66545;
}

.btn--outline {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid var(--color-headings);
}
.btn--block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn--stretched {
  padding-left: 6rem;
  padding-right: 6rem;
}

/* Input */

.input {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: var(--color-headings);
  font-size: 2rem;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #cdcbd7;
}

.input-group {
  border: 1px solid var(--color-border);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  display: flex;
}

.input-group .input {
  border: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.input-group .btn {
  margin: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .input {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

/* Cards */

.card {
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #f3f3f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.card__header,
.card__body {
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}

.card--primary .card__header {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: #fff;
}

.card--secondary .card__header {
  background: var(--color-secondary);
  color: #fff;
}

.card--secondary .badge--secondary {
  background: #02cdf1;
}

/* Plans */

.plan__name {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.plan__price {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.plan__billing-cycle {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.plan__description {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
}

.plan .list__item {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.plan--popular .card__header {
  position: relative;
}

.plan--popular .card__header::before {
  content: url(/images/popular.svg);
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: 5%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .plan__name {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

  .plan__price {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }

  .plan__billing-cycle {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  .plan__description {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
  }
}

/* Media */

.media {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.media__title {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.media__body {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.media__image {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* Quotes */

.quote {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--color-body-darker);
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.quote__text::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.quote__text::after {
  content: close-quote;
}

/* footer p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
 */

.quote__company {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: var(--color-headings);
  font-style: normal;
}

/* Grids */

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid--1x2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .grid--1x3 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

/* testimonials */

.testimonial {
  padding: 3rem;
}

.testimonial__image {
  position: relative;
}

.testimonial__image > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.testimonial__image > .icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  right: -32px;
}

/* Callout */

.callout {
  padding: 4rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.callout--primary {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: white;
}

.callout__heading {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.callout .btn {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.callout__content {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .callout .grid--1x2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  }

  .callout__content {
    text-align: left;
  }

  .callout .btn {
    justify-self: start;
    margin: 0 2rem;
  }
}

/* COLLAPSIBLES */

.collapsible__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.collapsible__heading {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.collapsible__content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__content {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Blocks */

.block {
  --padding-vertical: 6rem;
  padding: var(--padding-vertical) 2rem;
}

.block__heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.block--dark {
  background: black;
  color: #7b858b;
}

.block--dark .block__heading {
  color: white;
}

.block--skewed-right {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 80%);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--padding-vertical) + 4rem);
}

.block--skewed-left {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--padding-vertical) + 4rem);
}

.block__header {
  text-align: center;
}

/* nav */
.nav {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__list {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__item {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.nav__item > a {
  color: #d2d0db;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.nav__item > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__toggler {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav.collapsible--expanded .nav__toggler {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav__toggler {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav__list {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    visibility: ;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav collapsible">
      <a href="/"><img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
      <svg class="icon icon--white nav__toggler">
        <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#menu"></use>
      </svg>
      <ul class="list nav__list collapsible__content">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">VPS</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Domain</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok the problem was partially solved by adding "max-height: 100% opacity:1" to the .nav__list rule in CSS. But there is still another problem: when I press on the navbar, the list items expand and show in a block rather than a line, so they lose their display: flex property I think. I am pretty sure this is a problem caused by the javascript module the teacher gave us, but I have no idea about javascript so far.

Comment: You should then answer your own question, then create another question

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by adding `max-height: 100%; opacity:1` to the .nav__list rule in CSS.